# Unicode math with amsmath, new error

Tags: amsmath, luatex, unicode-math

After applying the most recent ctan updates, the following MWE does not compile with lualuatex. There is an error given ending with `\cs_set_nopar:Npx` that I can't make sense of.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

any ideas on how to work around this?

Comment: Known issue, already solved in the appropriate development tree and likely to be fixed on CTAN within a couple of days: https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/issues/98. If really urgent, grab the fixed `lualatex-math` from https://github.com/phst/lualatex-math.

Comment: great thanks, should i just delete this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Known issue](http://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/issues/98), which can be tracked back via [`unicode-math`](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/246) to [`lualatex-math`](https://github.com/phst/lualatex-math/issues/4). This is fixed in the development tree for `lualatex-math`, and is on its way to CTAN so should be in TeX Live/MiKTeX soon.  If really urgent, grab the [fixed `lualatex-math`](https://github.com/phst/lualatex-math).

Comment: I have current TL2012 but do not get an error??

Comment: @Herbert Well I certainly could reproduce the issue with the MWE from the linked `unicode-math` bug report, with an up-to-date `l3kernel` but not-fixed `lualatex-math`.

Comment: @Herbert tl 2012 hasn't caught up, yet, but the updated lualatex-math arrived on the ctan core sites within the last hour.  so, in principle, it could be available from tex live within a day.  personally, i would grab the package from ctan asap, and junk that copy when the tl version arrives.

Comment: @wasteofspace: the original poster has an up-to-date TL, the same as I have. So my question is why  I do not get the error

Comment: @Herbert I'm not sure if the OP has TL or has MiKTeX: it does not say. I tested using the development version of `l3kernel`, which of course is 'up to date', so would expect to see the issue even if TL has not yet got the appropriate files added.

Comment: uuh, you are right. In my brain I read TL ...

Comment: Is this actually fixed? Updated my TL today (both TL and all packages), and grabbed the newest version of lualatex-math from https://github.com/phst/lualatex-math, but I still get errors when trying to compile the MWE at https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/246. 

I.e.: ``! Undefined control sequence.
\lltxmath_set_mathchar:NN ...ardef #1\lua_now_x:n 
                                                  {lualatex.math.print_class...``

Comment: @dr.drgz Yes, it is fixed (both fixed parts are in TL2012, so you should not need to grab them separately). What is possible is that you have some mismatched files somewhere. What we'd need to solve that is your `.log` file. Either ask a separate question, or send me a copy (joseph.wright@morningstar2.co.uk): the latter might be easiest as this is probably a 'local issue'.